# x5t JWT Thumbprint Python Conversion

Tags: python, azure, jwt, base64, certificate

I'm trying to generate an x5t parameter for a header to make a request to Azure using a certificate to authenticate.
In the example given in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials, it's saying that the SHA-1 hash of 84E05C1D98BCE3A5421D225B140B36E86A3D5534 should give an x5t value of hOBcHZi846VCHSJbFAs26Go9VTQ=

When I try to convert this hash using the following, I find the x5t value to be ODRFMDVDMUQ5OEJDRTNBNTQyMUQyMjVCMTQwQjM2RTg2QTNENTUzNA==

What am I doing wrong in the conversion process?

```
import base64
x="84E05C1D98BCE3A5421D225B140B36E86A3D5534"
x5t = base64.b64encode(x.encode()).decode()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given SHA-1 hash

```
84E05C1D98BCE3A5421D225B140B36E86A3D5534
```

is a long hexadecimal number. In your code you treat it as a string, (e.g. "84") but you need to interpret it as hexadecimal representation of a byte array (e.g. first byte is 0x84):

```
import base64
x = "84E05C1D98BCE3A5421D225B140B36E86A3D5534"
x5t = base64.b64encode(bytearray.fromhex(x))
print(x5t.decode())
```

The result is:

> hOBcHZi846VCHSJbFAs26Go9VTQ=